# Creating a Net Salary in C# ADO.NET MVC... stuck and dont know if what i want is possible

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ado.net

We were asked to provide calculations (taxes & final income) from the salary that would be input in the employee profile in the website. I think I would be able to do this if I could INSERT the calculations of two SQL columns in a single column. For instance, column1 is "3" while column2 is "4"... I want column3 to be = to column1 + column2 but I don't know how to do it or it's possible. :(

I've already did the controllers/models for the constant values, but i'm really stuck on values with computations.

Comment: something like `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)  VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE1 + VALUE2)`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is this calculation always the same for each employee or can the calculation exchanged for some employees? Why do you don't calculate it in c#? A database is for storing data, not for calculating stuff. If you really want this in the database, a view could be an option. But don't confuse the underlying data with it's shown representation.

Comment: I'm going to second what @Rabban suggested as well. You can do it in C# before inserting it into the database, or you can create a stored procedure in SQL using that insert query i provided above, or an update query (if the records exist). Calculating in C# though, I'd definitely recommend as well with Rabban